# how to get Roundhouse to create db on second hard drive

Tags: sql-server, database-versioning, roundhouse

I want [Roundhouse](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) to create the db on a second hd (not the C drive which it does right now). Is there any way in Roundhouse to do this ? Iam using sql server 2008 r2 express. I tried the -cds option for custom db creation but it gives an error saying does not provide facility at this time.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must know how you would create it in T-SQL outside of RoundhousE. If you verify that it works with SQL Express, then you can provide the script to rh as text or (with the newest in trunk and soon to be released 0.8.5) you can point it to a script file that it will read.

If you are using an older version of RH, you MUST give the actual text to /cds and not a path to a file. That text cannot contain the word GO in it at all either.  Both of these things will be fixed when 0.8.5 is released.

HTH

Comment: yes. my db create script works fine outside of RH but I was getting an error when I tried -cds=mysript.sql. (error does not provide facility at this time). I will wait for 0.8.5. thank you

Comment: I checked out the trunk and ran build.bat, but just copying rh.exe from the build_output folder doesn't work. It crashesall the time. Any suggestions on how to "install" the trunk version?

Comment: Nevermind, got it: should have run ilmerge.bat as well and use that output: code_drop\RoundhousE\console\rh.exe